# Views Slideshow - Bullets or Numbered Pager not displaying

Tags: views, paging

I have used [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) to generate a page slideshow. The rotation / cycle is working fine but I need to display a bulleted pager. Since I am not able to display any kind of pager, I started with trying to show a numbered pager first which is not working for me.

I have basically used [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/1181966) to setup numbered pagers.

However, I do not see the numbers after doing the same.

[image]

I have enabled the page controls and current page index for testing purpose. Below is what I get using Devel Themer module and the developer tools.

[image]

I just increased the height of the area which is supposed to display the pager so that I can click that area to show the themer information. I cannot see anything rendered in the div responsible for displaying the pager. Also, as I see in the template which is rendering the code for pager is simple.

From the file "views-slideshow-pager-fields.tpl.php" the code is the following.

```
<div id="<?php print $widget_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
  <?php print $rendered_field_items; ?>
</div>
```

I do not understand why the pagers are not getting displayed. Where should I start looking for the fix?

Comment: Please, don't show the full browser window, in the screenshots. It makes the image difficult to see in the question, while we just need to see part of the browser window.

Comment: Agree but you have cropped off the Themer part and the div region which is important to see. Should we revert back to original image or this cropped part is enough to understand?

Comment: If you feel there is something missing in the screenshot, you can edit them, but please don't re-add the full browser window. The images you used were http://i.stack.imgur.com/ofNt1.jpg and http://i.stack.imgur.com/p96nh.jpg.

Comment: Cropped to the maximum extent which includes full information. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Thank you! Your collaboration has been fully appreciated.

Comment: change your theme to a drupal default theme to check if perhaps there is some css or override hidding the pager.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve **pager** using View Slideshow by following steps:

**Step 1:** In view, add **Global: View result counter** field and mark it as **Exclude from display**.

**Step 2:** Now click on Slideshow format settings, go to **Pager** part and select **Global: View result counter** field as a **Pager Type**.

[image]

**Step 3:** To give perfect bullets effect, you will have add some **CSS** as given below

```
.views-field-counter {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.views-content-counter {
    text-align: center;
    width: 29px;
    background: url(../bullets.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Step 4:** Please check out CSS Classes, ID's and HTML markups form below screenshot, which worked at my end.

[image]

Comment: Awarded the bounty, the clue was "Hide pager if only one slide exists" being unchecked. It was not working as it is supposed to be.

Comment: However the problem with bulleted pagers is not yet solved.

Comment: Try out the above steps to your local setup. Which theme you are using?